# JavaScript Canvas Left-Mouse-Down & Move Lag

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

In my game, when I hold down the left mouse and move it around, the game will become very slow. Although the right mouse button has the exact same function, doing the same with right click does not cause the game to slow down. Tested in Mozilla Firefox, IE 10, and Google Chrome, all with same results.

I'm not going to provide code right now because I don't see any way it could be related to the code, although I don't remember this happening before.

Here's the mousedown code showing I am using the same methods and left click makes the game run slow, right click does not.

```
function domousedown(e) {
    if(e.which == 1) {
        clearInterval(mousedownID);
            rightmousedown(e);
            mousedownID = setInterval(function() {
            this.rightmousedown(e);
        }, 500);
    } else if(e.which == 3 || e.button == 2){
        clearInterval(mousedownID);
            rightmousedown(e);
            mousedownID = setInterval(function() {
            this.rightmousedown(e);
        }, 500);
    }
    //return false;
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Edit: Found the issue, although I still don't understand why it's only on left click. Apparently with a lot of mousemove events then holding down left click and pressing other buttons, it causes the game to slow down. To prevent it I'll need to rewrite some mousedown methods.

Comment: There could be code that is running that you are not aware of, or have not noticed, or you do not know it's full side effects--you are going to have to post the code :p

Comment: Code is posted, what could have a side-effect on the left mousedown but not right?

Comment: Thanks. Where is domousedown bound? Ad where is mousedownID declared?

Comment: $("#chatlog,#skillBCanvas,#skillCanvas,#inventoryCanvas,#gameArea,#gameCanvas,#bgCanvas,#aCanvas").mousedown(domousedown);

var mousedownID; at the top

Comment: Okay, well that's a lot of DOM elements to bind to. I doubt it's the problem though. Assuming you're working in Chrome, are you familiar with Chrome's Timeline? https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/timeline -- you basically hit Record, then perform the actions you want to debug, then it prints out a timeline of all events being fired and triggered. Perhaps you could profile the left / right mousedown and see what's the difference.

Comment: Did you end up resolving this issue?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32786910/217408 fixed it for me