# Html Canvas lag when Left Mouse is down and moving on Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, canvas

I have created a canvas and I have added mouse events to it:

```
canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
context = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = screenWidth;
canvas.height = screenHeight;

... 

// CALLED AT START:
function setup() {
    // Mouse movement:
    document.onmousemove = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        target.x = e.pageX;
        target.y = e.pageY;
        angle = Math.atan2((target.y - localPlayer.getY()),
            (target.x - localPlayer.getX()));
        // Distance to mouse Check:
        var dist = Math.sqrt((localPlayer.getX() - target.x)
            * (localPlayer.getX() - target.x) + (localPlayer.getY() - target.y)
            * (localPlayer.getY() - target.y));
        var speedMult = dist / (canvas.height / 4);
        socket.emit("update", {
            ...
        });
    }
    document.onmousedown = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Now the issue is when I hold down the only left mouse button and move the mouse at the same time, my game lags a lot. Simply moving the mouse causes no lag. I have tested this on chrome and on firefox. It seems that I can only recreate the issue on chrome. Using the middle mouse button or right button has the same behaviour in the game and cause no lag. Only when using the left mouse button causes lag.

I have looked around for answers and found that I should prevent default behaviour like so:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

But that did not resolve the issue. I have also tried to update a number on the screen that represents the mouse position. And it updated normally. Only the game itself was lagging. Could it be that the onMouseMoved is never called whilst the left button is held down? But then why is it called with the middle and right button?

The issue should be with the code I a calling inside of the move method, because it works fine when I am not holding down the left key, and it works well on firefox. There must be something else going on.

EDIT: I decided to a recording on chrome to see what is going on. Here is the result:
[image: As you can see, I have highlighted the areas where I press the left button.]

What's really odd, when I press the middle mouse button or the right button, the game does the same thing, but it does not lag at all. What are you doing chrome?

EDIT: Test it out here: www.vertix.io note that not everyone seems to be able to reproduce this issue.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Are you really assigning two new event handlers every 0.033 s ? Why? Also, where is `draw()`

Comment: Instead of document I would use the canvas itself for the event...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But the onMove event is not being triggered whilst moving an holding down still.

Comment: what about moving object and when You release left button do socket.emit ?

Comment: I dont think this is the issue. Besides, the object would then only move on the server when I release the button, so it will teleport around on the server.

Comment: You need to create a MCVE if you want help

Comment: First move all that  code out of the `onmousemove` event and use `window.requestAnimationFrame` to update what you need. In the mouse move event just grab and store the mouse coordinates, it should not be where you do app logic. Also add `user-select: none;` style rule add '-webkit-' for Chrome,  to the body or canvas element to stop drag select. I dont know if this will solve your problem as you have not provided what is needed to replicate the problem

Comment: There might be a html solution: try adding oncontextmenu="return false;" to the canvas tag

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue here but everything goes fine. The click does not cause any problem on mousemove event. Certainly should be a issue in another code. Give us more details and more code :)

Comment: Maybe they up voted it, because they are having the same issue. My code is extremely long, providing a simple issue with a canvas and a click event wont cover it...

Comment: I highly doubt a dozen people will have the same issue when it requires extremely long code that cannot be easily reproduced. Your statement makes the question even more invalid though because it can apparently not be created in a minimal demo. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Had a look and could not reproduce the issue using current chrome beta. I also had a look for the mouse down event and could not find it. There is no mouse down event on the entire page, and I looked inside app.js and found no mouse down in that as well.

Comment: Yeah I removed it, since it was causing too many issues, even without it, my game still lags when holding down the left mouse and moving it. You could try to run a profile and see if the mouse has any influence on performance on your end. Might not be visible.

Comment: I had a very similar issue which I could not reproduce on a basic example. Luckily window.requestAnimationFrame solved this issue - thanks a lot, Blindman67!

Answer (score 6):

When you hold down the left mouse button and move it in the same time, you are **dragging**.

**Edit**: In some versions of Chrome, there is a bug (when I posted this answer I had it, now I don't), which causing the `drag` events to be fired even without the element having the `draggable` attribute. Normally, `drag` events should only be fierd from elements which have the `draggable` attribute set to `true` (except images and anchors who are drragable by default).

According to the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Drag_and_drop#events), when `drag` events are being fired, `mouse` events, such as `mousemove`, are not, which means that your function isn't being called.

A possible solution are to use the same function for both `drag` and `mousemove` events:

```
function mouseMove(e) {
    //do your things here
    ...
}

document.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove);

document.addEventListener('drag', mouseMove);
```

**Note**: If you'll use the same function for both events, you should be aware of which properties of the event you're using in the function, because of the difference between the `drag` and `mousemove` events. The two events doesn't contains the exact same properties and the behavior of some properties may not be the same in both of them.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered throttling?

Check out https://blog.toggl.com/2013/02/increasing-perceived-performance-with-_throttle/

Answer (score 0):

You have the mouse event on the document. As we can not see what you have on the document it is hard to know if that is a cause of your problems.

Try moving the mouse event to the canvas only, as that is the only place you need it I presume. No point handling events for the document if its not part of the game, plus document is last on the list if child elements have events attached. They go first and then it bubbles up to yours.

As it looks like you are using a framework of some type there is in all possibility another mouse event listener that is part of the frame work that may be slowing you down by not preventing default. You will have to search the framework to see if it has a listener for any of the mouse events.

And use `addEventListener` rather than directly attaching the event via `.onmousedown = eventHandler`
eg `canvas.addEventListener("mousedown",eventHandler);`

And add the event listener to the element you need it for, not the document.

Answer (score 0):

```
function mouseMove(e) {
//do your things here
...
 }

 document.onmousemove = mouseMove;

  document.ondrag = function(e) {
mouseMove(e);
//do another things
...
}
```

Comment: Try to add some description.