# JavaScript setTimeout() can't trigger itself

Tags: javascript, settimeout

How can a function, which is triggered by another function, get the mouse's position? Here's my code:

```
function myFunction(e){
    setTimeout(function(){
        if(isMouseDown == true){
            mouseX = e.clientX;
            mouseY = e.clientY;
            document.getElementById('myElement').innerHTML = mouseX + ' , ' + mouseY;
            myFunction(event);
        } else {}
    }, 100);
}
```

What this does is to display the coordinates when clicked. I need it to display them every 100ms if `isMouseDown == true`.

Thanks

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: You’ll probably want to use a mousemove event handler, and inside of that check if the button is pressed as well …

Comment: But why "can't trigger itself"?

Comment: `setTimeout(function me(){` then from inside, `me()`

Comment: I have a working code with the `mouseMove` - but I want it to refresh every 100ms

Comment: Anonymous functions can't trigger itself because it's anonymous.

Comment: @SenadMeškin: anon functions can call `arguments.callee()` to run themselves.

Comment: The `setTimeout` won't trigger itself

Comment: @dandavis thnx man, I totally forgot about arguments, my mistake :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way in Javascript for a random Javascript function to get the mouse position.  The current mouse position only comes from an event object for a mouse-related event.  So, if you want to keep track of the mouse position, then you can register an event handler for the `mousemove` event and for `mousedown` and `mouseup` to keep track of the button state.

If you only want to display the mouse position, ever 100ms, then you can set a timer so that it is only displayed that often, but you will need to keep track of the current mouse position in a mousemove event handler.

Here's a simple code example:

```js
var lastMouseX = 0, lastMouseY = 0;
document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
    lastMouseX = e.clientX;
    lastMouseY = e.clientY;
});

var mouseTimer;
document.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
    if (!mouseTimer) {
        mouseTimer = setInterval(function() {
            document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = lastMouseX;
            document.getElementById("y").innerHTML = lastMouseY;
        }, 100);
    }
});

document.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
    clearInterval(mouseTimer);
    mouseTimer = null;
});
```

```html
<div id="x"></div>
<div id="y"></div>
```

Comment: Please remove the "Demo coming in a bit..." part then this answer is good :-)

Comment: That is what comments are for. It is bad form to do that in an answer. I can probably quote you slews of meta posts about it.

Comment: You may need to add a listener for 'drag' events as well. See accepted answer regarding [Chrome does not fire mouse move while dragging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32547283/html-canvas-lag-when-mouse-is-down-and-moving).

Comment: @Traktor53 - Good point, but that depends upon whether the OP wants this to fire while dragging.  Usually dragging is a captured event where you don't want other mouse things firing.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit fuzzy what you're trying to achieve, however you're not going to get a periodic event if you're using`setTimeout()`. It sounds like you're looking for `setInterval()`. See the below example:

```js
  var mouseX = 0;
  var mouseY = 0;
  var isMouseDown = true;
  document.onmousemove = function(e){
    mouseX = e.pageX;
    mouseY = e.pageY;
  }
  setInterval("myFunction()", 100);
    
  function myFunction(){
    if(isMouseDown) { 
       document.getElementById('myElement').innerHTML = mouseX + ' , ' + mouseY;
    }
  }
```

```html
<div id="myElement"></div>
```

Comment: do you want to run the function on passing to setTimeout?

Comment: what is `isMouseDown`?

Comment: The variable that oP mentioned in his post... I didn't declare it in the example.