# "Left-MouseDown + MouseMove" blocking other events from firing

Tags: javascript, events, canvas, lag, mousemove

I'm having a strange issue, and I'm afraid that its actually a browser issue.

I'm developing a websocket multiplayer game. The game loop runs on `requestAnimationFrame`, and the positional/game data is received with Websockets.

My problem is, that whenever you hold down left-mouse and move your mouse, something is happening that causes other events to stall (like there's no breathing room to execute them) when mouse1 is released "or" you stop moving the mouse, all the blocked events fire. The animation-loop is not affected and runs as it should.

But my `socket.onmessage` event stalls, and no positions etc. is updated (making it look like server lag).

I have tried to unbind all mouse events, and the issue is the same.

I've also tried to add `stopPropagation()`, `preventDefault()` and `return false` to all `document` mouse events, but the issue remains.

I've recorded timeline to check whatever could be blocking it, but there is nothing. other than stacking of delayed events.

The timeline is basically 2 functions repeating.

1. tick = Function called by `requestAnimationFrame`
2. data = Function
   called by `socket.onmessage` event

**Normal:**

> tick, tick, tick, tick, tick, **data**, tick, tick, tick, tick, **data** .... and so on..

**left mouse-down + mouse-move:**

> tick, tick, tick, tick, tick, tick, tick, tick, tick, **Mouse1 released**, **data, data, data, data**

---

Note: this only happens with the left mouse button, so I could use right button for shooting etc. instead and the problem would not exists. but that would be a bad solution, since everyone will expect it to be mouse1, and the game will still lag when they hold mouse1, even though it has no function.

---

I've found the following threads with similar problems, but not one with a solution that actually works.

[JavaScript Canvas Left-Mouse-Down & Move Lag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30274677/javascript-canvas-left-mouse-down-move-lag)

[Html Canvas lag when Left Mouse is down and moving on Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32547283/html-canvas-lag-when-left-mouse-is-down-and-moving-on-chrome?rq=1)

[Mouse down and moving drops chrome canvas to 30FPS using CreateJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33024854/mouse-down-and-moving-drops-chrome-canvas-to-30fps-using-createjs?lq=1)

---

**[CodePen example](https://codepen.io/bQvle/pen/wGeqMG)** to reproduce the issue.

The client needs to be pressured, so you need to turn on the codepen built-in "Console" (It's doing some heavy logging to push the client). **And you'll need a 120hz+ monitor to provoke the effect.**

I know that it seems stupid, but you would get the same issues if you had an old computer and wasn't able to run 60fps on your 60hz monitor. This is purely to provoke the issue. The game needs to run, even when the client drops fps.

**[YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RsCpe6XOWuo)** showcasing the issue.

Comment: Could you try to narrow your code down while the bug still occurs and post a minimal live example so we can check what's wrong ? (If you find it by yourself doing so, it's even better) The only blind guess that comes to me would be a `drag` event.

Comment: Hi Kaiido, thank you for answering, I've made an example to reproduce the issue. https://codepen.io/bQvle/pen/wGeqMG please check Edit in OP for instructions

Comment: I've made a video to show the issue aswell: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RsCpe6XOWuo&feature=youtu.be

Comment: I just run into the same. It blocks in Chrome after mousedown and a few mousemove events. Works fine in Firefox though

Comment: For me it was listening for drag events on the same element like explained in http://stackoverflow.com/a/32786910/217408

Comment: I noticed it happends with Request Animation Frame only (in Chrome) so I've changed it to a fixed interval instead. even though i would love for RAF to work.